# Insert vertical spacing between list items

Tags: html, css

I have a simple list and I would like to add a border-bottom as the below image shows.

[image]

My solution

```css
li {
  height: 48px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
}

li::before {
  content: counter(li);
  background: #29C9CE;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  font-family: Raleway;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 38px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 5px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>full border bottom width</li>
  <li>full border bottom width</li>
  <li>full border bottom width</li>
</ol>
```

I tried even tried with after pseudo-element but nothing,

I want the result to be the same as the image above. thanks

Comment: the border is there, what is not working as intended?

Comment: But what you want?

Comment: @tacoshy please check the attached image, its there but the border width is not looking the same as image and numbers also not the same

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal updated the question info, I want the result to be the same as image provided , thanks

Comment: add a margin-bottom.

Comment: @tacoshy for future reference please add your answer  using code so that some one in future can understand your solution thanks

Comment: @TheDeadMan Your title of the question is ***Border Bottom with full width for list item*** And the thing you wanted was spacing between the `li`'s!

Comment: `width` is not equal to `spacing` 

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal am a human being I make mistake and English is not my first language so please understand me , but someone helped me , thanks and sorry for confusdion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add some top and bottom `margin` to each `<li>` element. Also, your [`counter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter()) usage needed to be updated so I added `counter-increment: listCounter` to the `<li>` elements and then used `counter(listCounter)` for the pseudo element `li::before` content. Try this out.

```css
li {
  height: 48px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
  margin-bottom: .75rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start; /* change this to center for text to be aligned with list number */
  counter-increment: listCounter;
}

li:not(li:first-child) {
  margin-top: .75rem;
}

li::before {
  content: counter(listCounter);
  background: #29C9CE;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  font-family: Raleway;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 38px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 5px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>full border bottom width</li>
  <li>full border bottom width</li>
  <li>full border bottom width</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: closer to what I want , why numbers shows 0?? the result should be the same as this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6z8R.png

Comment: Thanks man fo the solution this is what I was looking , I will accept your answer

Comment: @TheDeadMan *your* numbers show 0, in the code you provided. A question on stackoverflow is meant to have a very narrow focus. This question is for focusing on the gaps between list items (even though your title doesn't make this clear). If you'd like to focus on the numbering you must ask a separate question.